# Images are not getting the Div height when loading in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using jQuery to create an image grid which has images with different heights. **There are 4 columns** in my HTML and  I need to arrange every uploading image to the minimum height column. So I can expect the page balance of appearance. To do that I made the following live code but not working as I expect. When I appending images, images are not going to the correct column (minimum height column).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var itemsToLoad = 7

  for (i = 0; i < itemsToLoad; i++) {

    var col1 = $(".col1").outerHeight();
    var col2 = $(".col2").outerHeight();
    var col3 = $(".col3").outerHeight();
    var col4 = $(".col4").outerHeight();
    var sizes = [
      [col1, "col1"],
      [col2, "col2"],
      [col3, "col3"],
      [col4, "col4"]
    ];

    var min = 1000000;
    var mincol;
    for (k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
      if (sizes[k][0] < min) {
        min = sizes[k][0];
        mincol = sizes[k][1];
      }
    }

    $("." + mincol).append("<img alt='Image" + i + "Title' class='a' src='images/image" + i + ".jpg' style='width:100%'>");
  }

});
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.column {
  flex: 25%;
  max-width: 25%;
  height: max-content;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column col1">
  </div>
  <div class="column col2">
  </div>
  <div class="column col3">
  </div>
  <div class="column col4">
  </div>
</div>
```

I made another live code, **images are replaced with `<Div>`s** with different heights. It is working perfectly. When I loading a new div, it is  going to the correct column that has the minimum height.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var d1 = "<div style='background-color: #aaa; height: 75px; width:100%'>75</div>";
  var d2 = "<div style='background-color: #faa; height: 175px; width:100%'>175</div>";
  var d3 = "<div style='background-color: #afa; height: 95px; width:100%'>95</div>";
  var d4 = "<div style='background-color: #aaf; height: 45px; width:100%'>45</div>";
  var d5 = "<div style='background-color: #ffa; height: 75px; width:100%'>75</div>";
  var d6 = "<div style='background-color: #faf; height: 115px; width:100%'>115</div>";
  var d7 = "<div style='background-color: #aff; height: 125px; width:100%'>115</div>";
  var d8 = "<div style='background-color: #333; height: 155px; width:100%'>115</div>";
  var d9 = "<div style='background-color: #abc; height: 25px; width:100%'>115</div>";
  var d10 = "<div style='background-color: #cba; height: 105px; width:100%'>115</div>";

  var arr = [d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6, d7, d8, d9, d10];

  var itemsToLoad = 7

  for (i = 0; i < itemsToLoad; i++) {

    var col1 = $(".col1").outerHeight();
    var col2 = $(".col2").outerHeight();
    var col3 = $(".col3").outerHeight();
    var col4 = $(".col4").outerHeight();
    var sizes = [
      [col1, "col1"],
      [col2, "col2"],
      [col3, "col3"],
      [col4, "col4"]
    ];

    var min = 1000000;
    var mincol;
    for (k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
      if (sizes[k][0] < min) {
        min = sizes[k][0];
        mincol = sizes[k][1];
      }
    }

    $("." + mincol).append(arr[i]);
  }

});
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.column {
  flex: 25%;
  max-width: 25%;
  height: max-content;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column col1">
  </div>
  <div class="column col2">
  </div>
  <div class="column col3">
  </div>
  <div class="column col4">
  </div>
</div>
```

Why images are not working like this??

Comment: Please add your code in your question (preferably as snippet)

Comment: @MarkBaijens I added

Comment: It's hard to understand what is the desired result. Can you please explain in more detail ?

Comment: I think the problem is that the height of the image is not know yet because the images is not loaded yet and has no predefined height. Changes are pretty big that the next iteration (if not all iterations) already ran before loading the previous appended image.

Comment: @MihaiT If you run the second Snippet, you can see the last column is the least height one. I have 10 divs in my code and I loaded 7 of them. If I load the 8th div, it will go to the last column. It will make the appearance of page more balanced.

In the first snippet, I load images instead Divs and expect the same behavior. I load 7 images but 5th, 6th and 7th images are not in the least height columns.

Comment: @MarkBaijens I tried with #("img")on("load") but didn't give me even this much result

Comment: @DavidJohns, ignoring the fact you posted invalid javascript, I don't think an image onload event handler is gonna help you much here because of the for loop.

Comment: @DavidJohns I take back the previous statement. Found a solution with an onload event handler. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to do the trick.

First I append the images to a hidden container. Here the image will be loaded. All images get an onload event handler that will move the image to the right column based on your logic.

Note: the order that the images will be appended to the columns is a bit random since loading images is asynchronous.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var itemsToLoad = 7

  for (i = 0; i < itemsToLoad; i++) {
    //Code used to load dummy images starting with big size (700)
    var height = (itemsToLoad - i) * 50;
    
    var $img = $('<img>');    
    $img.attr('src', 'https://dummyimage.com/100x' + height + '/000/0011ff.png');
    $img.width('100%');
    $img.on('load', function() {
      //once the image is loaded move it to the proper column
      var col1 = $(".col1").outerHeight();
      var col2 = $(".col2").outerHeight();
      var col3 = $(".col3").outerHeight();
      var col4 = $(".col4").outerHeight();
      var sizes = [
        [col1, "col1"],
        [col2, "col2"],
        [col3, "col3"],
        [col4, "col4"]
      ];
      var min = 1000000;
      var mincol;
      for (k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
        if (sizes[k][0] < min) {
          min = sizes[k][0];
          mincol = sizes[k][1];
        }
      }
      $(this).appendTo("." + mincol);
    });
    $("#imagePreloaded").append($img);
  }
});
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.column {
  flex: 25%;
  max-width: 25%;
  height: max-content;
}

#imagePreloaded {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div id="imagePreloaded">
  </div>
  <div class="column col1">
  </div>
  <div class="column col2">
  </div>
  <div class="column col3">
  </div>
  <div class="column col4">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you this is seems correct. But why images are loading randomly? I mean when I reload the page, images are shuffling column to column

Comment: @DavidJohns because the code adds the images to the column after they are loaded. The `load` event handler is attached with: `$img.on('load', function() {});`. The loading of images happens asynchronous, so the order when they are done finished loading is not always the same. If you need that, then you need to build some logic to keep track of loading images and move them all together when they are all finished loading.